# What Good PostgreSQL Administration Tools Exist?

Tags: postgresql

Does PostgreSQL have good performance or administration tools?

I have been using postgres for quite some time now, but I still do not know a huge amount about ways to optimise and maintain a database, and keep it running well.

I have had a look through the manual, but since it is quite a mature product, I am assuming there are a couple of 'must-have' utilities for it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think that [PgAdmin](http://www.pgadmin.org/) is pretty popular. There's also [PhpPgAdmin](http://phppgadmin.sf.net), which is rougly analagous to the very popular [phpMyAdmin](http://phpmyadmin.net).

Answer (score 7):

Perhaps not what you're looking for, but plain old psql is excellent.  You can tell that the devs really meant for it to be a comfortable place to spend a lot of time.

Answer (score 5):

For general schema navigation [DBVisualizer](http://www.minq.se/products/dbvis/) is quite nice.

For performance information there are hardly any complete tools like MySQL Enterprise Monitor; I'd suggest to use pgFouine (already suggested) and any tool that can graph performance data (like Munin for example), collect the relevant information from PostgreSQL (pg_stat_ views/system tables) and the system itself (memory, cpu, disk utiliziation, etc.) and use this as a basis for deducing trends.

[This book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0672327562) has a few chapters on PostgreSQL performance; the [PostgreSQL Wiki](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Performance_Optimization) has a list of presentations on this topic.

And for specific questions there's always the [pgsql-performance mailinglist](http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-performance/) and it's [comprehensive archive](http://news.gmane.org/gmane.comp.db.postgresql.performance).

Answer (score 3):

[this guy](http://www.depesz.com/) has developed quite a few useful tools. take a look at his blog.

Answer (score 2):

For real simple tasks we use [phpPgAdmin](http://www.phppgadmin.org/).

> phpPgAdmin is a web-based administration tool for PostgreSQL. It is perfect for PostgreSQL DBAs, newbies and hosting services.

Answer (score 2):

[pgFouine](http://pgfouine.projects.postgresql.org/)

http://pgfouine.projects.postgresql.org/

pgFouine is a great log analyzer that has helped many times in the past.  It is really easy to set up too.  At one point the project ran on Rails, but I think it's using PHP now.

Comment: +1 because it is a great tool.   It looks like the project hasn't been touched in a long time.   It also has a lot of issues processing a lot of data (it is a PHP script after all).

Answer (score 2):

[TeamPostgreSQL](http://www.teampostgresql.com/index.jsp) is by far the best I've ever used.

- Works on any platform (Windows, OS X, or Linux)
- No stability issues that I've encountered (pgAdmin plagued me with them)
- Columns can be sorted by clicking on them (unlike pgAdmin)
- DB hosts not hard coded into a config file (unlike phpPgAdmin)
- Doesn't feel antiquated

Major drawback: it doesn't support SSL connections.